# Why do the three boxes appear when the parademon explodes?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

When Batman is fighting the parademon in the beginning of *Justice League*, he catches the demon with a net on the wall. The demon explodes after some screaming and twitching, leaving goo picturing the three mother boxes symbol refenced afterwards in the movie.

Why did this happen? We could say it is just trying to increase the mystery about the boxes in the beginning, because in hindsight there is no reason why an exploding henchman would leave these as a mark.

The other depictions I can remember do make sense as they were historic "aritfacts" of some kind.

Am I missing something or is this just bad writing?

[Scene](https://youtu.be/2g8TbkY-hgM?t=206)

Comment: _Am I missing something or is this just bad writing?_ I think this question and the answer to it can pretty much be used for any discussion about this film.

Comment: @Darren I thought so too, but maybe I really missed something...

Comment: The parademon doesn't just explode and leave a marking of the three boxes, he appears to have three markings that begin to burn, like miniature boom-tube's and explode from these three locations simultaneously, as if a boom-tube was opened inside it's body, leaving  which is why the mark is left. Given that parademons are Apokolyptian, and the motherboxes are Apokolyptian, could they just share design elements in the DCU to clue in viewers?

Comment: I'm betting it's just bad writing. I like the "head cannon" @AAlig gave above me but that doesn't seem to make sense. Imagine if some random alien exploded in "Infinity War" and left behind the mark of a gauntlet with stones. That would be ridiculous right? You wouldn't claim "shared design elements", you would just say that it's silly. Same thing here. The boxes and their "lore" are written in a silly way all through the movie.

Comment: The scene is only seen during Joss Whedon's cut. In Zack Snyder's Justice League, this scene doesn't exist, so don't take it as canon in this particular universe.

Answer (score 1):

Because the parademons have the motherboxes imprinted in them so when they detonate they     leave the imprint on what they die on.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! What's your source for this information? Is this your own theory or is this mentioned somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Because Batman is mortal and really has no connection to the mother boxes except if he were to contact Wonder Woman... They needed to give him something. It's also possible that the boxes originally aided in creating a parademon, which is why the symbol is imprinted on the object that it dies on. That symbol causes him to think that something bigger and much more dangerous is afoot, sending him to Aquaman and later to assemble the Justice League.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV. Maybe you can source your answer. It looks like it is your opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it was only there to give Batman the *greatest detective in the world*...a clue about something he doesn't understand yet...the only other clues he has are from other off screen 'sightings' and Luthor's notes.

On top of this, in the opening scene the criminal spells out for us, the monster is a solider/scout from space and they're coming because Superman is dead....This activates his next plan of building the justice league.

It was world class bad writing.

Comment: You are not answering the OP

Comment: I am, this is clearly bad writing.